# get the date from the file name and convert date value to date format

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the date from the file name and convert date value to date format

I'm using below code:

```
$getdate = $searchfile |  select Name, @{N="DateFile";E={$_.Name.substring(28, 8)}} 
echo $getdate.DateFile
```

The output is as below:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                                                                                    
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                                                                                                    
-a----       11/28/2017   2:18 AM            612 18230314810803001-000000000-20171128-XX                                                                                                  

Name     : 18230314810803001-000000000-20171128-XX
DateFile : 20171128
```

How can I format `$getdate.DateFile` to a date value?

Comment: this question is diffrent from the questions ask about this subject previously

Comment: `[datetime]::ParseExact("$($getdate.datefile)", "yyyymmdd", $null)`

Comment: @Ahmed Minor variations in the format string do not make your question different.